Creating github auth for a website that is not published
I am working on an application that requires GitHub authentication. I want to set up and test GitHub OAuth without having a public URL and any callback URL yet (I will publish once development is done). I also want to know how this setup compares with Google OAuth and what information I can retrieve from GitHub. Additionally, I need clarification on GitHub API rate limits, specifically the 15,000 requests per hour for OAuth apps. I'm still learning and would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried looking in github for help and they asked for a callback function and a url and since i am still testing, i was looking to ask if there is another way. Or you have to have a published website for it.
